# Unresolved reference: new in Exposed

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I'm starting Exposed ORM in use Kotlin from this [link](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed) 
I want to create User Table but show this error :

```
Error:(67, 14) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: new
```

User object and Entity class :

```
object Users : IntIdTable() {
    val name = varchar("name", 50).index()    
    val age = integer("age")
}

class User(id: EntityID<Int>) : IntEntity(id) {
    companion object : IntEntityClass<test5Gr.test5Artif.User>(table = Users)

    var name by Users.name    
    var age by Users.age
}
```

main :

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Database.connect("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1/test1", driver = "org.postgresql.Driver", user = "postgresql", password = "123")
    transaction {
            logger.addLogger(StdOutSqlLogger)

            create(Users) 
             User.new {
                name = "Mohammad"         
                age = 5
            }
            
        }
}
```

this error about `User.new {`
How can I solve this error? and i imported all require libraries to main

Comment: Try `gradle clean build` to console to check is it idea's error

Comment: And show please your `build.gradle`, maybe you not added `https://mvnrepository.com/repos/kotlin-exposed` repository